# Original frequency is not matching with suggestion frequency in SOLR

Tags: solr

Output for **"whs is"** - **(73)** which is a suggestion of **"who is"** varies than its actual original frequency **(94)**
For your reference attaching two images of the output

---

- Output for `/spell?spellcheck.q="who is"`

[image]

---

- Output for `/spell?spellcheck.q="whs is"`
  [image]

Any way to make both the frequency same

**Schema.xml** looks likes this

```
<field name="gram" type="textSpell" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false"/>
<field name="gram_ci" type="textSpellCi" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="false"/>

<copyField source="gram" dest="gram_ci"/>

<fieldType name="textSpell" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory" maxShingleSize="5" minShingleSize="2" outputUnigrams="true"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory" maxShingleSize="5" minShingleSize="2" outputUnigrams="true"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
<fieldType name="textSpellCi" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory" maxShingleSize="5" minShingleSize="2" outputUnigrams="true"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory" maxShingleSize="5" minShingleSize="2" outputUnigrams="true"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

**solrconfig.xml** look like this

```
<searchComponent name="spellcheck" class="solr.SpellCheckComponent">
    <str name="queryAnalyzerFieldType">textSpellCi</str>
    <lst name="spellchecker">
        <str name="name">default</str>
        <str name="field">gram_ci</str>
        <str name="classname">solr.DirectSolrSpellChecker</str>
        <str name="distanceMeasure">internal</str>
        <float name="accuracy">0.5</float>
        <int name="maxEdits">2</int>
        <int name="minPrefix">0</int>
        <int name="maxInspections">5</int>
        <int name="minQueryLength">2</int>
        <float name="maxQueryFrequency">0.99</float>
        <str name="comparatorClass">freq</str>
        <float name="thresholdTokenFrequency">0.0</float>
    </lst>
</searchComponent>
<requestHandler name="/spell" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="df">gram_ci</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">default</str>
        <str name="spellcheck">on</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.extendedResults">true</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.count">15</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.alternativeTermCount">10</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.onlyMorePopular">false</str>
    </lst>
    <arr name="last-components">
        <str>spellcheck</str>
    </arr>
</requestHandler>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think these frequencies are not the frequencies of the term in the same index :

- for /spell?spellcheck.q="who is" --> the frequency of *"whs is"* is the frequency of this term in the index of the spellchecker.
- for /spell?spellcheck.q="whs is" --> the frequency of *"whs is"* is the frequency of this term in the general Lucene index.

To have the same frequency, you have to use *solr.DirectSolrSpellChecker* instead of *solr.IndexBasedSpellChecker* (I guess) in your searchComponent :

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DirectSolrSpellChecker

**Edit :**  Depend of the way that you use to index your data.

Comment: I could not understand what u mentioned **the index of the spellchecker** and **the general Lucene index**....whats the difference ?...The query i used to get the suggestion for both is same....Also I am using only solr.DirectSolrSpellChecker....Please help....Your help is highly appreciated...

Comment: I thought you were using IndexBasedSpellChecker, which build its own index to search suggestions.
What fieldType are you using for spellChecker, what fieldType are you using for querying?

Comment: fieldType for spellChecker and querying are same...Please have a look at the question again snippet of the schema.xml is there....Hope it will help you...

Comment: Can you put the part of schema.xml where you define the type of field for you query? Or, maybe as you said you are using exactly the same fieldType for make query on your website and use spellChecker??
Maybe check with Luke what is the content of your index for the spellCheck field!

Comment: You can find Luke here :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28882522/solr-existing-index/28882756

Comment: Please check the **schema.xml** and **solrconfig.xml**....We are querying on **gram_ci**

Comment: Can you check with solr admin if there is no problem :
http://yourwebsite:8983/solr/#/core/select?q=whs+is
How much results do you have ?

Comment: as you can see total number of results are **94** that's what is there in original frequency but when i am getting "whs is" in the suggestion of "who is" why am i getting **73**...I am re indexing with different filters and tokenizer now... Do you know why such a thing happens and how to solve it

Comment: Do the same thing but search only on gram_ci field !

Comment: I get exactly same output

Comment: Didn't see your previous message. I have no more idea, sorry :(

Comment: I keep thinking to your problem, stay tuned !