# Solr : existing index

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I work with solr to index some data. I need to check existing index before start another index.
Is there any command to check existing index with solr?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to explore content of the index, you can use **Luke** which you can download in github :

https://github.com/DmitryKey/luke/releases

Comment: You can also use the solr admin page : http://example.com:8983/solr/#/core/schema-browser

Comment: Thank you for this recommandation.. i have another question about solr.. actually, I need to implement a destributed indexing with solr 4.10.3..It's possible?!

Comment: Sorry, I don't use distributed indexing. Ask a new question if you need to.